# How can I get the version of the application (defined by tag version in pom.xml) in quarkus specially?

Tags: quarkus, microprofile

I moved from a plain Java EE application to quarkus.io. 
In Java EE I had the a properties file with 
`version=${project.version}` and reeading this file in an JAX RS endpoint. This worked very well.

```
@GET
public Response getVersion() throws IOException {
    InputStream in = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("buildInfo.properties");
    if (in == null) {
        return Response.noContent().build();
    }
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(in);
    JsonObjectBuilder propertiesBuilder = Json.createObjectBuilder();
    props.forEach((key, value) -> propertiesBuilder.add(key.toString(), value.toString()));
    return Response.ok(propertiesBuilder.build()).build();
}
```

Now that I am using quarkus and MicroProfile, I wonder if there is a better approach.

I tried it with the ConfigProperty setup from MicroProfile.

```
@ConfigProperty(name = "version")
public String version;
```

But I get the following error:

`Property project.version not found`.

Here is my build section of my pom.

```
<build>
    <finalName>quarkus</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
            <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.CR2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>build</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${surefire-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <systemProperties>
                    <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Is there any solution / better approach?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try

```java
@ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.application.version")
String version;
```

Also you can read the Implementation-Version from the manifest.

Comment: Hi @anamarija, I tried that. `@ConfigProperty(name ="quarkus.application.version") String quarkusVersion;`. Gaves me the error: `No config value of type [java.lang.String] exists for: quarkus.application.version`. Sorry, I should have included that in my question!

Comment: Could you post your pom.xml. Are you using the ```quarkus-maven-plugin```
Basically the quarkus build maven plugin takes the value of ```project.version``` and puts it into the ```quarkus.application.version``` if it isn't already set.

Comment: I included the build section.

Comment: Did you manage to get this working?

I'm having the same problem in version 1.0.1-Final.

I've also tried to set the version via Maven like this in application.properties:

    quarkus.application.version=${project.version}

But this didn't work either.

Comment: No, I did not. Maybe we should ping the quarkus guys.

Comment: There was a bug: https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/6255

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if my approach is the best case scenario but you can try this:

**pom.xml** :

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/application.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
   </resources>
```

In **application.properties** use version property:

```
quarkus.version=${quarkus.platform.version}
```

Then use it as a config property:

```
@ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.version")
String version;
```

Comment: Beware: this shows the quarkus platform version, not the application version, which is what the OP asked.

Comment: This worked great for me.  I was able to incorporate a number of pom/project properties including build time.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way:

```java
String projectVersion = ConfigProvider.getConfig().getValue("quarkus.application.version", String.class);
```

Or `.getOptionalValue()` etc

Comment: What's the source of this? I always just inject it.

Comment: https://quarkus.io/guides/config#programmatically-access-the-configuration - I find it useful to use this technique eg inside a function.

Comment: I see what you mean, but that's not the current way for me. It's the way if you don't have Dependency Injection available. The way to go with DI is the one from the accepted answer, see: https://quarkus.io/guides/config#inject-the-configuration - maybe you can update the answer to just point out that the answer is just another way? I think that would be helpful to others!