# quarkus-maven-plugin does not add implementation-entries to MANIFEST

Tags: java, maven, quarkus

I want to read the current artifact version of my maven-project inside my of a RESTful service. My code is written in JAX-RS (Quarkus).

I am using a the following `pom.xml` snippet:

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
        <artifactId>quarkus-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${quarkus.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <archive>                   
            <manifest>
            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>build</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
```

I read the version with the following java snippet:

```
      String vendor = getClass().getPackage().getImplementationVendor();
```

It seems to me that the `quarkus-maven-plugin` is ignoring that line since `maven-jar-plugin` is working perfectly fine (I used this in a different project):

```
      <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
```

I do not have a really profound knowledge of maven and quarkus yet.

Am I making a mistake setting up the `quarkus-maven-plugin`?
Is there a workaround which does not include reading directly from the `pom.xml`?

Thank you for helping me.

EDIT:
I will mark this thread as "answered" as soon as the following issue 
is resolved (opend by @Guillaume Smet):
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/5023

EDIT:
Issue is resolved as of today.
https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/5100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `addDefaultImplementationEntries` won't help, we build the jar ourselves and we don't push any of this information to it.

I created https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/5023 for this.

For the time being, you can either push the information to the manifest yourselves (we enhance it if you have an existing one) or inject the values we derive from the POM files in your REST resources with:

```
@ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.application.name")
String name;

@ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.application.version")
String version;
```

Comment: Thank you for answering and opening that issue, for now I will add the information myself (your first mentioned workaround).

Comment: The annotation loopup for version is not working. 
See also:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58306053/how-can-i-get-the-version-of-the-application-defined-by-tag-version-im-pom-in?r=SearchResults