# Quarkus / microprofile read pom.xml property

Tags: java, maven, quarkus, microprofile

What i need to do is retrieve project version from pom.xml from java code.

I'm currently use the snippet as the official documentation suggests:

```
@ConfigProperty(name = "version")
public String version;
```

**application.properties** :

```
version=${quarkus.platform.version}
```

Therefore seems like pom.xml properties is not available through **application.properties** without any boilerplate. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this as i posted on: [quarkus read pom.xml properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58306053/how-can-i-get-the-version-of-the-application-defined-by-tag-version-im-pom-in)

**pom.xml** :

```
<resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
            <includes>
                <include>**/application.properties</include>
            </includes>
        </resource>
   </resources>
```

In **application.properties** use version property:

```
quarkus.version=${quarkus.platform.version}
```

Then use it as a config property:

```
@ConfigProperty(name = "quarkus.version")
String version;
```

Comment: Yes seems to work that way! Is there any quarkus specific way to do it so?

Comment: @tzou85 not sure about any quarkus specific way to do it so.. You can ping the quarkus guys for something like that

Comment: This is quite confusing, since the Quarkus documentation says that there is already a property defined to read the version, namely: quarkus.application.version, but this doesn't work either. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58306053/how-can-i-get-the-version-of-the-application-defined-by-tag-version-im-pom-in?r=SearchResults&s=12|59.3560